# md-next-button not working with angular material

Tags: html, angularjs, css, angular-material

I'm new in angular Material, I want to customize the tabs where I overdid the css of `md-tabs` like bellow:

```css
.md-tabs.md-default-theme .md-tab, md-tabs .md-tab {
  background-color : white !important;
  margin-right:1em;
}
```

and my code html is:

```html
<md-content> 
  <md-tabs md-dynamic-height="" md-border-bottom="" style='border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0; !important'>
    <md-tab ng-repeat="itemTab in vm.tabs" label="{{itemTab.label}}" ng-if="vm.showedTabs.indexOf(itemTab.id) > -1">
      <div ng-include="'main.html'"></div><!--ici on insert nos pages de workflow-->
    </md-tab>
  </md-tabs>
</md-content>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="vm.addNewTabs()">Add new tabs</md-button>
```

the function named `vm.addNewTabs()` is used to add new tabs dynamically and it's work fine. The problem when I override the css class, the **md-next-button** doesn't work, it appear but does not working and if I remove `margin-right:1em;` all it work fine.

Any one has a idea why this appear?

Comment: Can you create a snippet or bin for this?

Comment: you can take a look here http://plnkr.co/edit/1Vdv6EExHSZ6aTBFC5v3?p=preview

Comment: I can't find the `md-next-button`

Comment: You have to add several tabs by clicking the add new tabs button, then it will appear.

Comment: you have to use the inspector in order to see it in the code, or you see the button of pagination doesn't work. you can remove `margin-right:1em;` and add new tabs by clicking in the button and you will see the button of pagination work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The md-next-button calls the canPageForward function inside of Angular Material to determine if the button should be enabled. This function looks like this:

```
function canPageForward () {
    var lastTab = elements.tabs[ elements.tabs.length - 1 ];
    return lastTab && lastTab.offsetLeft + lastTab.offsetWidth > elements.canvas.clientWidth +
        ctrl.offsetLeft;
  }
```

Apparently your custom CSS isn't taken into account when calculating the sizes and this function is returning false, therefore disabling the button.

Comment: This  also happen with me. i remove the custom css. it works.

Answer (score 0):

i use next scss fix

`md-tabs-canvas {
    md-pagination-wrapper, md-tabs-dummy-wrapper {
        white-space: nowrap;
        md-tab-item, md-dummy-tab {
            float: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Maybe you should elaborate more your answer.